# How to remove rows with question mark (?) in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to clean data that has question marks.

I tried using:

```
df_census_new = df_census[~df_census.astype(str).apply(lambda row: row.str.contains("\?").any(), axis=1)]
```

But it raised this error:

> AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values

I was expecting to be able to remove the rows that have question marks (?) in them.

Comment: can u provide your dataframe cuz I created a dummy dataframe and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your columns containing `?` must be of string type. So, the best way is to use `str.contains()` in the following way:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', '?David', 'Eve'],
    'Age': [25, 30, 35, '?', 45],
    'Income': [50000, 60000, '?', 80000, 90000],
    'City': ['New York', '?', 'Los Angeles', 'Chicago', 'Houston']
}

df_census = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

which is:

```
      Name Age Income         City
0    Alice  25  50000     New York
1      Bob  30  60000            ?
2  Charlie  35      ?  Los Angeles
3   ?David   ?  80000      Chicago
4      Eve  45  90000      Houston
```

so that

```
string_columns = df_census.select_dtypes(include='object').columns

df_census_new = df_census[~df_census[string_columns].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('\?', regex=True)).any(axis=1)]
```

which gives

```
    Name Age Income      City
0  Alice  25  50000  New York
4    Eve  45  90000   Houston
```